# Буденный и буденовский

Tags: орфография

Скажите, пожалуйста, а почему БудеННый, но порода лошадей — будеНовская? Куда девается второе Н?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вторая Н никуда не девается. Порода называется БУДЁННОВСКАЯ.

БУДЁННОВСКАЯ - отечественная порода верховых лошадей, выведенная в 1921—48 в конных заводах им. С. М. Буденного и Первой Конной армии в Ростовской области Б. п. соединила в себе лучшие качества донской и чистокровной верховой пород. (БСЭ)

Comment: Кстати, мне в литературе и в интернете часто попадалось именно с одной Н.